# Trying to copy large file unmounts the hard drive after a while

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive

I am using windows 10 fully updated. I have two external hard drives, both plugged on the USB SS ports on the motherboard. Both drives are using veracrypt, and have a exFAT file system.

I am trying to copy a single 330 gigabyte file from one disk to the other. Both are USB2. The copy starts fine and keeps going for around 10-15 minutes, then suddenly I receive an error message (not very clear, it just says that an error has occurred). At the same time, the receiving disk is unmounted and disappears from both the file browser and veracrypt.

I have no other really useful information to give. The only thing that may seem related is this message from the system log

The IO operation at logical block address 0x6bb4600 for Disk 2 (PDO name: \Device\0000008c) was retried.

I am checking the disk for bad blocks, but I am almost done and it seems fine.

Why is it failing and how can I make it work?

Comment: Yes, these SE sites are Q&A sites, so questions and answers are welcome here. :) The problem was I could come up with at least three different questions that may have been your question. Why should I have guessed? Please note I needed to carefully read your post before writing the previous comment; and I didn't give up on it, I thought I could help you maybe, depending on which possible question you want to ask.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the encrypted file to an *unencrypted* drive, and then from there back to the encrypted? While this would require extra steps, including possibly wiping the intermediated storage, it might be feasible as a work-around.